# Regex - Validate that the local part of the email is not ending with a dot while only allowing certain characters without using a lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I was using a lookbehind to check for a dot before the @ but just realized not all browsers are supporting lookbehinds. It works perfect in Chrome but fails in Firefox and IE.

This is what I came up with but it certainly is messy

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-]\.?)*[a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-]@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]$
```

Is there a simpler and/or more elegant way to do this? I don't think I can negate the dot (^.) because I'm only allowing certain characters to be present in the local part.

Comment: You are allowing a backtick in username but avoiding a dot after `@`. Why? However, you could do this `^([\w&^*%#~{}=+?\`-]+(\.(?!@))?)+@(\w+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$`. Also it seems you forgot to quantify TLD part.

Comment: For some reason since lookbehinds weren't working, I automatically assumed lookaheads wouldn't either. This actually works, awesome! Thanks @revo and thanks for the TLD warning good eye :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `` ([a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-].?)*[a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-] `` part is not messy, but inefficient, because the `*` quantifies a group containing an obligatory part, `[...]`, and an optional `\.?`. Instead of `(ab?)*a`, you may use `a+(?:ba+)*` that will make matching linear and swift, in your case, `` [a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9&^*%#~{}=+?`_-]+)* ``.

More, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` equals `\w` in JS regex, you may use this to shorten the pattern.

Besides, the last `[a-zA-Z]$` pattern only matches a single letter, you most probably need `[a-zA-Z]{2}$` there, as TLDs consist of 2+ letters.

So, you may use

```
^[\w&^*%#~{}=+?`-]+(?:\.[\w&^*%#~{}=+?`-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKsB2J/2).